# Implementing several globalization Calendars, Timezones, in an MVC4 website

Tags: datetime, asp.net-mvc-4, calendar, timezone, globalization

sorry but I am really confused here. I read some threads but they could not make it clear for me.

I have an MVC 4 website which is expecting visitors from around the world. The website is in Arabic, and I want all visitor to use the Arabic language, `ar-SA` culture.

Now comes the problem: dates. Visitors should be able to choose from two supported calendars. Some will choose `GregorianCalendar` and some will choose `HirijiCalendar`.

Q1: Where to set the calendar (user-dependent) for better performance?

What I have done is a base controller which all controllers inherit from. In `OnActionExecuting`, I try to change the: `Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.Calendar`
to the visitor preference, which was read from database upon signing in.

Q2: Will this line of code affect: the *current request* only, the *current session* only (this visitor), or the *whole application* (all visitors)? I am afraid it will affect others, I do not know anything about thread scope… I am afraid that changing thread calendar in `OnActionExecuting` every time is too bad for the performance…

Q3: If I store dates in database according to UTC (like AddedOn, EditedOn), where should I convert it to whatever time zone of a visitor? in controller code? Will the website become slow to do this every time I query the database? What is the best practice here?

Thank you and excuse me, I'm a beginner.

Comment: Since you have three distinct questions, I recommend searching for each of them separately.  You'll probably find they each have their own answers already.  In particular, recognize that time zone and culture/calendar are separate concerns.  They may seem associated, but if you think it through you'll realize they are unrelated.

Comment: I will. I just don't know where to put the code or if there is a best practice. I do not know if threading.thread... will harm the performance or interfere with other visitors.

Comment: There's a good answer for that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2863593/634824).  There are answers to the other two also. Search.  If you don't find one that fits well, then ask about that separately, with specific details about what you tried, what worked and what didn't.  If your concern is performance specific, you should discuss that and explain what performance issues you are seeing (if any).  Focus on each of your three questions separately for best results.  Thanks.

Comment: Thank You for the link, I read it... I will do more search.

Comment: Is that ASP.NET MVC4? Could your tag the question accordingly, please?

Comment: I did tag it with `MVC`. sorry.. I should have tagged it with `asp.net-mvc-4`...